# Two buttons in same line > Relative Layout inside Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

So I need to put two buttons in the same line so im trying with Relative Layout inside the Linear Layout but they only can move below and not sideways.

How it should be:

`TextView`

`TextView`

`TextView`

`TextView`

`Button1`  `Button2`

The Code:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

`<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

`</RelativeLayout>`

`</LinearLayout>`

They are supposed to stay beside each other(buttons) but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: why are you wrapping the buttons in a relative layout? just use a linearlayout with horizontal orientation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: you could add layout_weight=1 to the buttons if you want them to be the same size

Comment: Ok, but they are not that much far apart, how do I set them to be a little more a far ?:

Comment: And the second way didn't worked well, button2 is in top of button1.

Comment: use layout weight as 1 to both the buttons

Comment: well change the alignRight to toRightof

Comment: or if you still are not getting it take a look at  http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012_10_01_archive.html if you might need something like that

Comment: Keep in mind I left out the "android:" on all of the attributes. `<Button id="@+id/button1" layout_width="0dp" layout_height="wrap_content" layout_weight="1" text="Button" />`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the existing code only.
Use the id of first button in the second button.

```
<RelativeLayout 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

Take a close look at the relative layout, it now uses `wrap_content` for it's height and `match_parent` for it's width. Also notice the `alignParent` parts inside the button xml. Using a `RelativeLayout` is not the only way to do this but could be better if you want the buttons to float on the right and left side. You could also use a `LinearLayout` with it's orientation set to `horizontal`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Rolf

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I had a case where I wanted:

```
    [     Button1     ]
    [Button2] [Button3]
```

and when I tried embedding a linearlayout within a linear layout, the formatting was correct but the buttons didn't respond.

The way I resolved it was to put Buttons 2 & 3 inside a table, and if you wanted to apply this solution to your example it would look something like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRowForButtons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```